# Removing the content from an svg tag with snapsvg

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using http://snapsvg.io/ 
When the user clicks on a chip to bet it should show an svg image with the chip color, then if the user clicks another chip it shoud show that new chip. And it does but I'm not being able to remove the content before appending a diferent svg content, so what's happening is that svg gets put on top of previous svg.

I don't really want to append more content, I want to replace it. But I don't seem to find any other option besides .append()
That's why I try to .removeData() before appending but is not working. It keeps putting the next svg image on top of the previous one.
I hope I'm making a little sense here.

This is how my code looks like on react.

```
         componentWillReceiveProps () {
           if (this.props.chipSelectedSvg) {
             const tipChipSnap = snap('#tipChip');
             const tipChipSvgContent = Snap.parse(this.props.chipSelectedSvg.content);
             tipChipSnap.removeData();
             tipChipSnap.append(tipChipSvgContent);
            }
         }

         render () {

           return (
             <div id="tips-tooltip-container" style={{visibility : tooltip}}> 
               <svg id="tipChip" className="chip" viewBox="-15 -20 120 120"></svg>
             </div>
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Element.remove()` method.

http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.remove

Comment: i'm not sure. Element.remove removes an element from a "snap drawing surface". As far as i understand it he wants to replace the whole surface.
so a regular replaceChild would do i guess.